# Shared preference FormatExeption: Unexpected character (at character 1). in. Flutter Desctop

Tags: dart, sharedpreferences

[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 1)

After deleteting chared preference in my app, it is working fine,
Actually this happen after upgrating dart sdk